# Unable to start agent node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

Unable to start agent node in Jenkins.

Master machine showing error exception in log file.

```
[12/01/14 16:21:44] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 

10.0.11.120:22.
Connection refused: connect
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not established!
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.getRemainingAuthMethods(Connection.java:1030)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.canAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.java:82)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:207)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:169)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1173)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[12/01/14 16:21:45] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[12/01/14 16:21:45] [SSH] Connection closed.

[12/01/14 16:23:44] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.0.11.120:22.
```

Comment: can you remote into that slave otherwise?

Comment: I have the same problem and I can remote to that machine

Comment: Can you try using port 443 instead of 22 i.e. 10.0.11.120:443

Comment: I am running into this same issue. Using port 443 instead of port 22 had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your slave machine is Mac then 
Go to **System Preferences** -> **Sharing** and enable **Remote Login** then try again.

Comment: I can log in. and have the same problem

Comment: its a windows node for me and its the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I have trace the log of the slave.

```
tail -f /var/log/*.log
```

And I have seen this message.

```
Sep 20 14:51:43 clicrdv.aws-eu-west-01.batch-01.adm sshd[1035]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-96,hmac-md5 server hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
```

Then, I have deleted this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
```

And restart ssh.
Then no problem at all.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to install the Java Cryptography Extension for your JVM. Without that the RSA key size is limited and authentication is not being established.

See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26495 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and resolved it by replacing the IP address with the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved for my by replacing host name by IP Adress.

See also: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26379?focusedCommentId=249378&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-249378

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424405) answer.

Comment: It's opposite. That answer was replacing ip with host. But for me it worked replacing host with ip